# Why is my edit worker page show different worker details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i currently doing a worker edit page. Normally when we click on a worker then click edit page, in the edit form will show this worker info like name, but now my edit page show different worker info (I want to edit worker A but my edit form show worker B details)

Also my delete function can't work.

worker controller

```
def show
 @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
end

 def edit
  @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
  @worker.company_id = params[:company_id]
  @role = Role.all
 end

 def update
  @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
  @company_id = Company.find(params[:worker][:company_id])
  @role_id = Role.all
  if @worker.update(worker_params)
  @worker_role = Role.find(params[:worker][:role_id]).worker_roles.update(worker: @worker)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @worker
 else
   render 'edit'
  end
end

#DELETE
def destroy
 @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
 @worker.destroy
 flash[:success] = "Worker deleted"
 redirect_to worker_url
end
```

edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit worker") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: @worker, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :phone_number %>
  <%= f.number_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :address %>
  <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :role_id %>
  <%= f.select(:role_id, Role.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id] }, {class: "form-select"}) %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :company_id , value: 2%>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @worker.name)%>

<h2>Worker Info</h2>

<%= render @worker %>
<div class="row">
 <aside class="col-md-4">
   <section class="stats">
    <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
   </section>
   <div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary"><%= link_to "Back to workers", workers_path %></button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_worker_path(current_worker) %></button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary"><%= link_to "Delete", @worker, :confirm => "Are you sure?" ,:method => :delete%></button>
  </div>
 </aside>
</div>
```

Update

If i click on my own admin worker info page then click edit can show the edit page and my worker info but if i click other worker info and edit will transfer me to login page. Is that any validation i need to do?

[After click edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWqKZ.png)
[worker info page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNuXR.png)

And for the delete button still can't work, when i click the delete button, i see at the console there seem like it didn't have delete method, it give get method. Is that the reason it cannot work?

[When i click on the delete button show at the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IyNv.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my edit page didn't have the current worker details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897877/why-my-edit-page-didnt-have-the-current-worker-details)

Comment: no, because i didn't see have any answer at there

Comment: Sorry, that was an automated message I had no idea StackOverflow was going to post on my behalf. I did not post that message. I marked this question as a duplicate. I did not expect that action to post such an idiotic message on my behalf. Sorry.

Comment: Is okay, nvm. Did you have any idea to solve this problem~

Comment: I'm taking a look, but could use some more info. Can you please include the `show` controller action? And your `shared/stats` view? And any relevant controller filters if you have them?

Comment: I have update my worker controller with show action, and the shared/stats didn't have anythings inside

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like you're linking to the edit page using the wrong worker ID. You're using some `current_worker` variable when it probably should be `@worker`.

Try this instead for the edit button in `show.html.erb`:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary"><%= link_to('Edit', edit_worker_path(@worker)) %></button>
```

2. Your deletion doesn't work because you're not providing a path at all.

Try this instead for the delete button in `show.html.erb`:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary"><%= link_to('Delete', worker_path(@worker), method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?') %></button>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but edit there have some problem, i have update my post, can you help me to check it.

Comment: It seems like you have a controller filter like a `before_action` causing your edit not to work. Can you please include your entire worker controller file, and entire `ApplicationController` file?